# How to capture a word boundary in Swift NSRegularExpression?

Tags: swift, regex, nsregularexpression

I would like to capture all *words* within a string which start with some prefix. For example all words which start with a `t`

```
if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"t[^ ]+"#, options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive) {
    let input = "this is the best test"
    let matches = regex.matches(in: input, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: input.count))
        
    for match in matches {
        print((input as NSString).substring(with: match.range))
    }
}
```

In the code above I am using a simple space as delimiter (`#"t[^ ]+"#`) and the output is as expected:

```
this
the
test
```

However, not only spaces but all word boundaries should be considered. So I replace the space with `\b` to match all boundaries (`#"t[^\b]+"#`). However, this does not work:

```
this is the 
t test
```

It seems that this code does not look for word boundaries but simple for `b`... Why is this?

I thought using `#` before and after the regex would create a raw string and thus deliver the `\` correctly to the regex system. So `#"t[^\b]+"#` should the same as `"t[^\\b]+"` and be translated to `t[^\b]+`, shouldn't it?

Or is the word boundary operator `\b` not available in Swift regex?

**EDIT:**

According to the [ICU Documentation](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html) `\b` matches a **word boundary**, thus `[^\b]` (anything but a word boundary) should not be the same as `[^b]` (anything but a b), should it?

However, it seems that `\b` can not be used in sets, can it? But `\B`should do the same (anything but a word boundary).

So I tried using `#"t\B+"#` instead. However this does not find any match at all.

**The question remains:** How to match a word boundary in Swift NSRegularExpression?

Comment: Do you mean you need `pattern: #"t\w+"#`?

Comment: If you put `t[^\b]+` in a regex online tool, does it really show what you want? Did you meant `\s` instead of `\b`? Or maybe `\w+`?

Comment: Unrelated but don't use `NSString` and `NSRange(location:length:)` in Swift. There are (more reliable) native APIs

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `#"t\w+"#` would not match `t123` for example. I would like to match all *words* starting with a t, where a "word" is something delimetered by a word boundary. @Larme `\b` should match a word boundary according to ICU Documentation, where `\s` only matches whitespaces.

Comment: `\b` matches - *detects* - a word boundary only outside a character class. Inside it, it behaves differently in different regex engines/programming languages. In ICU regex, `[\b]` matches a `b` and not a backspace (`\x08`) char as in many other regex flavors, ICU is a very specific regex library, and there are many more weird things about this regex flavor (e.g. bare POSIX character class support.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#"t[^\b]+"#` string literal results in a `t[^\b]+` regex and it simply matches `t` and then one or more chars other than a `b` char (the `[^\b]` is equal to `[^b]` in ICU regex flavor).

To match a `t` and then one or more word chars (that is, up to the next leftmost word boundary), you can use

```swift
pattern: #"t\w+"#
```

where `\w+` will match one or more word chars.

A `[...]` is a *character set/class*. And a character class is meant to match *characters*. `\b` is a word boundary *only outside* a character class, because a word boundary is *not a character*, it is a zero-width assertion that matches a certain *position* in a string. All zero-width assertions lose their special, "zero-width" meaning in a character class. `[.$]` doesn't mean a `.` or end of string, it matches either a `.` or `$` char. `[.\z]` does not match `.` or the very end of string, it matches `.` or `z` as `\` is omitted since `\z` is not a valid escape sequence.

Also, `t\B+` makes very little sense as `\B`, also a *zero-width assertion*, matches a *location* in the string that is not a word boundary position. Note that zero-width assertions do not *consume* text, i.e. no text is added to the overall match memory buffer, and the regex index remains where it was before trying the zero-width assertion pattern. By adding `+` after `\B`, you just tell the regex engine to match a *location* after `t` that is not a word boundary, so the regex engine matches `t\B+` the same way as if it were a `t\B`, i.e. it only matches a `t` that is followed with a word char (letter, digit, connector punctuation).

`\w` matches (and *consumes*) word chars, so if you need to match (and really get as a result) any chars after `t` till the first word boundary, you just need to use this `\w` pattern, `t\w*` or `t\w+` (if there must be at least one word char after `t`).

Comment: According to the ICU Documentation (https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html) `\b` matches a **word boundary**, thus `[^\b]` (anything but a word boundary) should not be the same as `[^b]` (anything but a b), should it?

However, it seems that `\b` can not be used in sets. But `\B`should do the same (anything but a word boundary). But why does `#"t\B+" does not work?

Comment: @AndreiHerford Right, `[...]` is a *character set/class*. And a character class is meant to match *characters*. `\b` is a word boundary *only outside* a character class, because a word boundary is *not a character*, it is a zero-width assertion that matches a certain *position* in a string. All zero-width assertions lose their special, "zero-width" meaning in a character class. `[.$]` doesn't mean `.` or end of string, it matches either `.` or `$` char.`[.\z]` does not match `.` or the very end of string, it matches `.` or `z` as ``\`` is omitted since `\z` is not valid string escape sequence.